# asp.net control (.ascx) with dijit?

Tags: asp.net, dojo, ascx

i've tried to get an asp.net dropdownlist control to become a dijit combobox but it's not working.

i've tried this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUserID" dojoType="dijit.form.ComboBox" runat="server" 
    DataTextField="FullNameAndUserName"
    CssClass="stdtext" DataValueField="UserID" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
    AutoPostBack="True"
    meta:resourcekey="ddlUserIDResource1" EnableTheming="False">
    <asp:ListItem Text="(All Users)" Value="0" meta:resourcekey="ListItemResource1" />
</asp:DropDownList> 
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/dojo/dojo.js"></script> 
   <script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require('dijit.form.ComboBox');
</script>
```

the path to dojo.js is relative to the containing parent page of the ascx control and loads fine according to firebug.

the rendered html is this:

```
   <select id="invoiceReport1_ddlUserID" class="stdtext" dojotype="dijit.form.ComboBox" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'invoiceReport1$ddlUserID\',\'\')', 0)" name="invoiceReport1$ddlUserID">
   </select>
   <script src="../scripts/dojo/dojo.js" type="text/javascript">
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
```

looking at the examples from http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/form/ComboBox
i cant see why the resulting select tag is not a combobox.

i've also tried this:

```
HtmlGenericControl ctrl1 = new HtmlGenericControl("Script");
ctrl1.Attributes.Add("Type", "Text/Javascript");
ctrl1.Attributes.Add("src", "../Scripts/dojo/dojo.js");
this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(ctrl1);


HtmlGenericControl ctrl2 = new HtmlGenericControl("Script");
ctrl2.Attributes.Add("Type", "Text/Javascript");
ctrl2.InnerText = "dojo.require('dijit.form.ComboBox');";
this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(ctrl2);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: after adding 
 ctrl1.Attributes.Add("djConfig", "parseOnLoad: true");

i'm now getting appearence problems...

i get a ▼ then an X then a textbox then all of the list items appear as a bulleted list beneath all of the other content.

Comment: onchange is straight JS, not a url, so you'll probably want to drop the "javascript:"

Answer (score 1):

the solution ended up being this:

you must refer to dijit.css either in your stylesheet or directly.

Comment: dijit.css alone doesn't really function.  You'd typically want to pull in one of the themes, like tundra.css (or just the relevant widget css files in the Tundra theme) which would then pull in dijit.css.  And put class='tundra' on the body.